# Loop the recordset returned using mssql in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I am working on application in node.js where I am using `mssql` package for connecting to MS SQL database.
I am using

```
var ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(conn);
```

When I call `execute` method on prepared statement I get the recordset.

```
ps.execute({[OPTIONAL_INPUT_PARAMS]}, function(err, recordset)
```

Now I want to iterate through the `recordset` returned in the callback.
Please suggest how can I be able to iterate through the result.

Comment: `forEach` comes to mind ?

Comment: Yes thanks. When I put this question and then I found one link saying: I can do `recordset.length` as the recordset is just as javascript json object. I used simple for loop with `recordset.length` and printed the `recordset[i]`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
for (var i = 0; i < recordset.recordsets[0].length; i++) 
        {
               console.log(recordset.recordsets[0][i].id);
        }
```